# webpack: exporting an ES6 bundle

Tags: webpack, undefined

I am trying to create a simple ES6 bundle that can be used in another project (that also uses webpack).

Here is the simple file I am building:

### lib.js

```
const foo = {
  bar: 1
};

export default foo;
```

Here is the webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: [
     './lib.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "dist/bundle.js",
        pathinfo: true
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015', exclude: 'node_modules' }
        ]
    }
    [...]
```

This is built as expected.

The problem is that when trying to use it in another project, the import is always empty and doesn't contain my foo object:

### test-app.js

```
import { foo } from 'lib';

console.log(foo);  // undefined
```

Comment: Have you tried using appropriate babel plugin like `"presets": ["es2015"]` in your `.babelrc` file?

Comment: That's what I am doing already.

This is my .babelrc file:

{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}

Comment: I should add that my lib is actually a node_module and the main (in the package.json file) points to the bundle generated by webpack.

It is then installed using npm link into the other project.

Answer (score 0):

In the loaders section of your Webpack config, you are telling Babel to not compile files existing in the `node_modules` directory. If you add a second loader entry to compile just the module or scope you need, Babel will compile as well.

Here's an example to include one module:

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules\/(?!module_name\/)/
      }
    ]
  }
  ...
}
```

Here's an example to include a specific scope:

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules\/(?!@scope\/)/
      }
    ]
  }
  ...
}
```